# What is the term for how aerodynamic something is? Aerodynamicicity?

Tags: adjectives

On more than one occasion I've attempted to say something like:
*It depends on the object's aerodynamicicity* and had to stop myself before finishing the last word.

Is there really only one option: to just re-word the sentence into *It depends how aerodynamic the object is* or is there another word I could use here?

Why should something like *opaque* and *aerodynamic* both be handled differently? Both are adjectives that can be swapped in and out of each-other's sentences, yet when it comes to saying something like:
*It depends on the object's opacity* we can't swap *opaque* and *aerodynamic* anymore.

(I'll accept *aerodynamicicity* should probably be *aerodynamicity* if this rule is allowed to work here.)

Alternatively, should the term be *aerodynamicry* - as with *mimic* and *mimicry*?

-

(The same question applies for *hydrodynamic* or just *dynamic*.)

(*Opaque* (*opacity*) could be substituted for *ferocious* (*ferocity*) or *generous* (*generosity*), etc.)

Comment: I think it should be ***aerodynamics***: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aerodynamics

Comment: Perhaps *aerodynamicality*? (But really I agree with the previous comment, *aerodynamics* is the right word.)

Comment: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hmm, I guess why I'd naturally swerve away from that word is because the `aerodynamics` of an object can refer to all the features that might affect the overall effect, whereas `how aerodynamic` something is is a scalar like `opacity`.

Comment: Can aerodynamics be evaluated in simple terms of more or less? I'm no expert but I would have thought that an object's aerodynamics contain multiple features. I doubt that there can be a single scale upon which they can be expressed, so that one object can be said to be better than another - just different.  (However I feel sure the same must be true of opacity.)

Comment: What about 'aerodynamism'?  https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Aerodynamism

Comment: @WS2 I completely agree, but when I want to say `the aerodynamicity of an object` I _mean_ the overall effect (probably because I'm referring to what effect that's going to have on it's speed (1 number)).
@RamPillai That word does sound like a possible candidate here.

Comment: @WS2 Put more simply, my thinking is:
When you refer to how `opaque` something is, you refer to its `opacity`
But when you refer to how `aerodynamic` something is, you refer to its `aerodynamicity` / `aerodynamism`?

Comment: The term is *drag* but it runs in the opposite direction. More aerodynamic means less drag.

Comment: @PhilSweet I think that's actually the most accessible answer here, it's scaling in the wrong direction but it'd work in normal conversation when referring to the effect on an object.

Comment: **It depends on the object's aerodynamics.**

Comment: @MikeGraham consider these 2 referential sentences though:

`When talking about an object's _aerodynamics_, we are talking about the features which make it aerodynamic.`

vs

`When talking about an object's _aerodynamicity_, we are talking about how much drag is does or does not cause overall.`

(Just as when we are talking about a solution's toxins, we are talking about the toxins within, but when we are talking about a solution's toxicity we are talking about how toxic it is.)

Comment: @Rogod I know nothing about the technicalities here, but I seriously doubt what you say. Suppose as an engineer you deliberately want to create drag. You need to change the aerodynamics. So you introduce "more aerodynamics to create the drag", don't you? Your approach seems to suggest that "drag" is the opposite of "aerodynamics". Mine is to say that aerodynamics is the science which studies things like drag versus its antonym - propulsion.

Comment: @PhilSweet The OED definition of "aerodynamics" is *The branch of science that deals with the properties of air and other gases in motion and the interaction between a gas and objects moving through it.* How can a "branch of science" be the antonym of "drag"?

Comment: One can always say “drag coefficient” not just “drag”

Comment: @WS he isn't using the term that way. He's using it as [of or having a shape which reduces the drag from air moving past.](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+aerodynamic&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS724US727&oq=define+aerodynamic&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l7.6285j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: related - https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/hcs3d/a_question_on_how_to_describe_an_attribute_of_an/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One reason that *aerodynamicity* is awkward is that it's new.

OED has *opacity* first appearing in 1575; *mimcry* in 1671; *ferocity* in 1606 and *generosity* before 1500.

However, **dynamicity** is listed, as "A synonym of valency or atomicity. (In modern dictionaries.)" I'm not sure what "modern dictionaries" means; the entry dates from 1897.

Since *dynamicity* is known, one might expect *aerodynamicity* to be fine. But it isn't.

It isn't because it's just too cumbersome. *Dynamicity* already has five syllables, and that's really the maximum in normal use. *Aerodynamicity* could appear almost unnoticed in a scholarly work, but it doesn't really fit into day-to-day discourse. The best course of action there is to rework the sentence.

Comment: Given `dynamicity` is permitted, could `aero-dynamicity` be justified if `aerodynamicity` is not?

Comment: That is something I'd considered. It's pronounced almost as two words, with a small pause at the hyphen. That would make it easier (and put it into the "five syllables or fewer" set).

Answer (score 2):

Since *aerodynamic*, when used to mean *low drag* and *streamlined*, is a layperson's term and uses the term as a quantifier rather than just as *pertaining to forces of moving air*, it is the wrong term to try to nominalize and get the meaning of *the degree of low dragginess*. (Just how it came to be used that way eludes me.)

Better by far is to use the rearranged sentence you posted in your question.

There are a couple of uncommon and unattractive alternatives.

1. *Aero slipperiness*. This is used exactly as you want to use it. It appears to be established in road bike racing lingo at least, and it is instantly recognizable.
2. *Streamlinedness*, usually used selfconsciously and sometimes in quotes. This seems to show up mostly in biomechanics discussions.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the word "aerodynamic" the wrong way to begin with. The word "aerodynamic" is not indicative of how streamlined something is. A correct use of the term would be this: "In order to find how much drag is induced by the body, and how to remedy it, you will need to study the aerodynamics of it first". You would not say, "I need to study how aerodynamic the body is". Aerodynamics encompasses fluid mechanics of compressible gasses moving around a body. When you say the word "aerodynamic" it should always be followed by a noun such as "properties" or "forces".

Comment: You need to add authoritative references to substantiate such direct claims. And note that ELU deals with general English usage considered acceptable, not merely (and sometimes not) stipulative definitions used in say Technology Institutes. [CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/aerodynamic) includes the example 'an aerodynamic car' and [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/aerodynamic) '_aerodynamic_ [adjective] ... 1.1 Of or having a shape which reduces the drag from air moving past.' Whether the adjective is gradable is another matter.